# Prove that $\lim_{a \to 1} a^{1/n} = 1$ using ε-δ definition

Tags: analysis

Question as above. I have factorised $a-1$ into $(a^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)(1+a^{-1}+...+a^{-n})$ and stucked all the way. How could I continue the way to prove using delta-epsilon definition of limit?

Comment: The factorisation is wrong.

Comment: What's $n$ here dear ?

Comment: $n$ in here stands for natural numbers exclude 0. Feel sorry not to mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
I'm assuming that $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
As suggested in the comments, you made a mistake when computing the factorization. After you find the correct one, you will see that
$$ \left\vert a^{\frac{1}{n}}-1 \right\vert = \frac{\vert a-1\vert}{\left\vert a^{\frac{n-1}{n}}+\ldots+a^{\frac{1}{n}}+1 \right\vert} \leq \vert a-1\vert, $$
given that $a\geq 0$.
Can you finish?

Comment: @MarkViola Oh, indeed. I will add that to my answer, thanks.

Comment: Take $δ=ε$ to complete the proof?

Comment: @WeiLam Yes! ${}{}$

Comment: @Sobi Thanks all the way!! I never thought this question could stuck me for few days due to my incorrect way of factorisation. I get doubted when I was trying to prove it using limit definition.

Comment: @WeiLam No need to thank me, you basically did all the work yourself!